# Windows10のタスクバーに登録するためのコマンドラインツールを探しています

Tags: windows-10

Google が配布している、Win7appid というものがあり
コマンドラインでWindows7のタスクバーにショートカットを登録できるものでした。

Google Code Archive - Long-term storage for Google Code Project Hosting.
https://code.google.com/archive/p/win7appid/

これと同じようなWindows10版はないでしょうか？

下記のプロジェクトで利用していたのですが、Win7のときはタスクバー登録できたのですが、Win10ではできなくなってしまいました。

https://www.facebook.com/notes/standard-software/excel-makeapp-framework-%E5%9F%BA%E6%9C%AC%E6%A9%9F%E8%83%BD-project01/947984808636642/

このプロジェクトではExcelVBA使ってますが、特にExcelに限らず、vbsファイル(やexeファイル)のショートカットファイルをWindows10のタスクバーに登録したいのです。

ご存知の方おられましたらよろしくお願いします。

Comment: この記事あたりが参考になりそうです。[Pin program (with parameters) to Taskbar using PS in Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59778951/9014308), [How to get verb for pin to taskbar in Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35600392/9014308), [Pin program to taskbar using PS in Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31720595/9014308)

Comment: Google Code はあくまでホスティングサービス (ファイルの保管・配布場所) として利用されているだけであり、必ずしも Google がプログラムを開発・配布しているわけではありません。

Comment: ！！！ありがとうございます。調べます。

Comment: 遅くなったのですが、調べた所どれも動かない様子です。
Windowsのアップデートによって挙動が変わっているようで、現在は動かなくなっている、というのがより正確な状況の様子です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「解決した」とはありませんが、コメントにUp Voteがあったので回答化しておきます。
紹介した中のどれかが該当すれば良いですね。

英語版StackOverflowのこれらの記事で同じ話題を扱っているようです。
[Pin program (with parameters) to Taskbar using PS in Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59778951/9014308)

> Windows 10でPSを使用してプログラム（パラメーター付き）をタスクバーに固定する
>
> I am able to pin programs to the Windows 10 Taskbar using the below code (thanks to this StackOverflow question). However, if I try to add a command-line parameter to the program, like the example below, it doesn't work. It seems like the code presumes the target executable doesn't have any parameters.
>
> 以下のコードを使用して、プログラムをWindows 10タスクバーに固定できます（この StackOverflowの質問に感謝します）。ただし、次の例のように、プログラムにコマンドラインパラメーターを追加しようとしても、機能しません。コードは、ターゲットの実行可能ファイルにパラメーターがないことを前提としているようです。

承認回答

> Here's a function that will do the following:
>
> - Use the full path provide to create a temporary shortcut.
> - Add the arguments / Icon / Hotkey and description if any
> - Invoke the pin verb on the temporary shortcut to create the pinned item.
>
> The pinned item will reference your application and not the temporary shortcut (which has been deleted by then anyway)
>
> To use, just fill out the parameters (Only Path is mandatory)
>
> 以下は、次のことを行う関数です。
>
> - 一時的なショートカットを作成するには、フルパスを使用してください。
> - 引数/アイコン/ホットキーと説明があれば追加します
> - 一時的なショートカットでピン動詞を呼び出して、ピン留めされたアイテムを作成します。
>
> 固定されたアイテムは、一時的なショートカットではなくアプリケーションを参照します（それまでに削除されました）
>
> 使用するには、パラメータを入力するだけです（パスのみが必須です）

以下、詳細なスクリプトの例と解説が続いていますので参考に。

[How to get verb for pin to taskbar in Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35600392/9014308)

> Windows 10でタスクバーへのピンの動詞を取得する方法は？
>
> I'm trying to pin an exe to taskbar in windows 10. But I'm not able to find verb for pin/unpin to taskbar.
>   I have tried the same code on windows 7 and 8.1 machine, its working fine, but its not working on windows 10 machine.
>
> 私はWindows 10でexeをタスクバーに固定しようとしていますが、タスクバーに固定/固定解除の動詞を見つけることができません。
>   私はWindows 7と8.1マシンで同じコードを試しましたが、うまく動作しますが、Windows 10マシンでは動作しません。

承認回答

> Posted by Misha Rudiy on 11/5/2015 at 7:30 AM
>
> For new OS installs you can still pin to the taskbar via the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\TBDEn registry key.
>
> Example: In an SCCM Task Sequence, I have a batch script that runs after the "Setup Windows and Configuration Manager" step that basically contains reg-adds.
>
> Syntax (REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\TBDEn" /v SBOEM0 /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%%ALLUSERSPROFILE%%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Mozilla Firefox.lnk" /f)
>
> You can add additional links by adding values and incrementing SBOEM0 to SBOEM1 etc.
>
> Thanks to Wayne Ye http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/185512/Programmatically-PIN-shortcut-onto-Taskbar-on-Win7.aspx for pointing this method out back in 2011.
>
> Somethings to note, there seems to be little public documentation on this. It most likely only works as a post imaging step (see my reference to SCCM), but I am not 100% sure. The above mentioned site states that it takes place during the DASH process. I wasn't able to find any documentation on how\when a DASH process works with Windows OSes. This may be information that is only privy to OEMS.
>
> Misha Rudiyが2015年11月5日午前7時30分に投稿
>
> 新しいOSのインストールでは、HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\TBDEnレジストリキーを介してタスクバーにピン留めすることができます。
>
> 例：SCCMタスクシーケンスには、基本的にreg-addsを含む「Windowsおよび構成マネージャーのセットアップ」ステップの後に実行されるバッチスクリプトがあります。
>
> 構文（REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\TBDEn" / v SBOEM0 / t REG_EXPAND_SZ / d "%% ALLUSERSPROFILE %%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Mozilla Firefox.lnk" /f ）
>
> 値を追加し、SBOEM0をSBOEM1などにインクリメントすることで、追加のリンクを追加できます。
>
> 2011年にこの方法を指摘してくれたWayne Ye http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/185512/Programmatically-PIN-shortcut-onto-Taskbar-on-Win7.aspx に感謝します。
>
> 注意すべき点として、これに関する公開文書はほとんどないようです。ほとんどの場合、ポストイメージングステップとしてのみ機能します（SCCMへの参照を参照）が、100％確信はありません。上記のサイトは、DASHプロセス中に行われると述べています。DASHプロセスがWindows OSでどのように動作するかについてのドキュメントを見つけることができませんでした。これは、OEMだけが知っている情報かもしれません。

[Pin program to taskbar using PS in Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31720595/9014308)

> Windows 10でPSを使用してプログラムをタスクバーに固定する
>
> I am trying to pin a program to the taskbar in Windows 10 (RTM) using this code:
>   This worked on Windows 8.1, but no longer works on Windows 10.
>   If I execute $item.Verbs(), I get these:
>   As you can see, there is no verb for pinning it to the taskbar. If I right click that specific file, however, the option is there:
>   Questions:
>   Am I missing something?
>   Is there a new way in Windows 10 to pin a program to the taskbar?
>
> このコードを使用して、プログラムをWindows 10（RTM）のタスクバーに固定しようとしています：
>   これはWindows 8.1では機能しましたが、Windows 10では機能しなくなりました。
>   $ item.Verbs（）を実行すると、次のようになります：
>   ご覧のとおり、タスクバーに固定する動詞はありません。 ただし、その特定のファイルを右クリックすると、オプションがあります。
>   質問：
>   何か不足していますか？
>   Windows 10でプログラムをタスクバーに固定する新しい方法はありますか？

承認マークは無いですが、多数の回答が寄せられています。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
かつては動いていたようですが、私が試した所、現在はどれも動かないという状況でした。
情報感謝します。